# Is there an addon for making the timeline BPM-based?

Tags: audio, snapping, timeline

I've found one called Rhythm 1.0 but it seems it no longer exists. Anybody know of something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Timeline markers.**

Have a vague recollection of Rhythm. To display on timeline Could use timeline markers.

[image]

Test script. 180 bpm at 24 fps comes out as 8 frames per beat (fpb). A timeline marker is added at every fpb frames starting from 1. The "|" name can be set to nothing "", or whatever.

```
import bpy
scene = bpy.context.scene

bpm = 180
fps = scene.render.fps
fpb = 60 * fps / bpm
print("frames per beat", fpb)
frame = scene.frame_start
while frame < scene.frame_end:
    scene.timeline_markers.new("|", frame)
    frame += fpb
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, this worked alright!  This literally made me say: "okay, screw it, I have to learn python now" So if I ever make an addon of this sorts I'll be sure to quote you on this. Thank you.